# CursorAdapter + ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm using a ListView with a CursorAdapter with the ViewHolder pattern.

The listview contains cells with a title and a subtitle and I'd like to access a row by position to change the subtitle text.

I'm trying to achieve this by using the myListView.getChildAt(idx).getTag() to access the cells ViewHolder and manipulate the subtitle text but the getTag() is returning null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're correctly setting the tag for your rows?

Comment: Have you explicitly set the tag? It will return null otherwise. You should just be able to use the index and not need the tag. Posting your code might help us understand better.

Comment: Please post relevant code and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the approach was right the problem was that I was accessing a bad index and this issue took me 5 hours like crazy. I went to sleep and in the morning I solved it in a minute :D ... Thanks for the help!